# Opening a Processes in it's own instance

Tags: c#

Is there a way to start a process in a separate instance with it's own mouse and keys that don't interfere with the use of other processes.

For Example: Let's say I want to make a program that automates a program and it requires clicking on locations and trying in keys. While this is happening I want to be able to do other things on the computer like nothing is happening.

Attempt At Clarity:
So this separate instance would be given inputs for the program based on what it sees or something like that. No separate output from the user. More like the program is running the process in the background while youre using your computer like normal

Comment: hmmm... How? are you going to use different mouse and keyboards on the same machine? if so how you define which one does what? or I didn't understand your question totally

Comment: I tried my best to further explain

Comment: You'll need to use the Windows API.  You can use the `SendInput` API and you'll then simulate keyboard and mouse input.  I don't know for sure but I wouldn't be surprised if that did interfere with actualy physical mouse and keyboard input going on at the same time.  Alternatively, you can send the appropriate messages directly to the appropriate windows using the `SendMessage` API, e.g. `WM_SETTEXT` to set the text in a text box or `BM_CLICK` to click a button.

Comment: Thank you friend, I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET for input simulation using WinForms.

For keyboard input you need [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) and for the Mouse you can use  [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx). Although it should be noted that the OS - usually - only includes one mouse pointer, and so setting it's position is machine wide.

For a better simulation of mouse input, you will need to resource to p/invoke. The recommended pattern is to use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you could look for existing solutions that emply this technique, such as [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/).